# How to return all column values as xml attributes from DB2?

Tags: sql, xml, r, db2, rodbc

So usually use would use `*` to indicate that you want all columns or `M.*` if you wanted all columns from a table with an alias `M`, but this doesn't seem to work inside of an `XMLATTRIBUTES` function of `DB2`. However, listing the required columns by name works (I'm working with the `RODBC` driver in `R`):

```
qry <- "
SELECT XML2CLOB(
    XMLELEMENT(NAME \"my_object\",
        XMLATTRIBUTES(M.COLUMN1 AS \"column_1\", M.COLUMN2)
    )) as xml
    FROM MYTABLE M
fetch first 100 rows only
"
```

Result:

```
                                            XML
1: <my_object column_1="1000002" COLUMN2="1"/>
2: <my_object column_1="1000003" COLUMN2="2"/>
3: <my_object column_1="1000004" COLUMN2="1"/>
4: <my_object column_1="1000005" COLUMN2="2"/>
5: <my_object column_1="1000006" COLUMN2="2"/>
...
```

I am having trouble generalizing to all columns as in the following query:

```
qry <- "
SELECT XML2CLOB(
    XMLELEMENT(NAME \"my_object\",
        XMLATTRIBUTES(M.*)
    )) as xml
    FROM MYTABLE M
fetch first 100 rows only
"
```

Result:

```
       V1
1:                                                                                     42601 -104 [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "*" was found following "*".  Expected tokens may include:  "NEXTVAL CURRVAL".  SQLSTATE=42601\r\n
2: [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect '\nSELECT XML2CLOB(\n    XMLELEMENT(NAME "claim",\n        XMLATTRIBUTES(F.*)\n    )) as xml\n    FROM LRD.FEA F\n    where F.CPU_STMP_DT_CEN = 20\n    and F.CPU_STMP_DT_YR = 13\nfetch first 100 rows only\n'
```

I am not sure if the `*` shortcut is simply unsupported inside of `XMLATTRIBUTES` or I should construct some kind of alias of my own that pastes the column names into `XMLATTRIBUTES` but I am not sure how to do that.

Additionally, I would accept if each column name value was its own `XMLELEMENT` nested inside `my_object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having R directly handle the development of the XML document instead of a DB2 specific function. SQL is considered a special-purpose language and hence not the best option to handle flat files, dynamically render content, and fluidly connect with other APIs.

Below you can import a simple select query using `*` into a data frame. Then iterate through each column of data frame as new attributes:

```
library(XML)
library(RODBC)

# ODBC DB CONNECTION
conn <-odbcDriverConnect('driver={DB2 Driver};host=hostname;
                          database=databasename; UID=username;PWD=password')
df <- sqlQuery(conn, "select * from tablename;")
close(conn)

# CREATE XML FILE
doc = newXMLDoc()
root = newXMLNode("Data", doc = doc)

# ADD NEW NODE WITH AN ATTRIBUTE
for (col in names(xmldf)) {  
  my_object = newXMLNode("my_object", attrs = c(column = col), parent=root)
}

print(doc)

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
  <my_object column="first column"/>
  <my_object column="second column"/>
  <my_object column="third column"/>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was specifically trying to do the xml in db2 because I was having performance issues doing it in R.

Comment: I understand. But curious what performance issues? Data capacity? RAM? I often advise not to use SQL beyond its limited scope of [DML, DDL](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=ddldml.php), and data retrieval. If not R, use Python, PHP, Java, C#, VB, or other general-purpose languages to create documents like XML as they have extended libraries for such purposes. I found one programmer sending an email with an SQL stored procedure! Yikes!

Comment: It was RAM. I have since worked around this issue and now I am doing something like a batch query and doing the xml processing (JSON in python now actually) on batches. Thanks for your answer though!